# Firebase database (WEB) - Securely editing data without a server running Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I realize this is probably impossible, but setting up a server running the firebase admin sdk and communicating with that seems like it's a bit of a hassle so and kinda removes everything that was an advantage about Firebase. If I have to communicate with the server constantly it seems like it'd be much faster just to make it all in php and MySQL.

Is it in any way possible to edit data constantly (Health, money, lvl, etc), without letting the user touch it, without running the Admin SDK?

Like, I guess what I'm trying to ask is, if there's a way that you can call the database using php instead and then edit the data from there so you prevent the user from editing any of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Firebase Database from PHP through its REST API. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) for that, or [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-database+php).

But where would you run that PHP code? Because it'll either be on server or on your own machine, where you could in that case just as easily run the Firebase Admin SDK and get a much nicer API.